# Transform two rows in one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have an auditing system which logs all the changes that occur in all the system tables. Basically, this is how the AuditLog table looks like:

[image]

Currently I am creating a couple of sql views to query different kind information. Everything is ok except for one point. If you take a look at the image again, you will see I have a SubscriptionMetadata table which is a key-value pairs table with 2 fields (MetaName and MetaValue). What the immage shows is that the subscription has a new watermark which value is 'Licensed copy: Fullname, Company, V...'.

What I need is transform, in my view, these two rows in just one with the following form:

```
41 - Insert - SubscriptionMetadata - 2012-10-19 - 53DA4XXXXXX - Watermark -  Licensed copy: Fullname, Company, V...
```

I really cannot imagine how I can do it or search for it neither.

There is another problem (I think), these rows comes always in that order: MetaName first and then MetaValue. That´s the only way to know they are related.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Do you want these in separate columns or do you want the data concatenated into a single column?

Comment: No, i need them in two columns. 'Watermark' in the fieldname column and 'Licensed copy: Fullname, Company, V...' in the fieldvalue column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot see your full table structure you can transform the data the following way.  Both of these solutions will place the data in separate columns:

```
;with data(id, [action], [type], [date], [col], metatype, value) as
(
    select 41, 'Insert', 'SubscriptionMetaData', '2012-10-19', '53DA4XXX','Metaname', 'Watermark'
    union all
    select 41, 'Insert', 'SubscriptionMetaData', '2012-10-19', '53DA4XXX','MetaValue', 'Licensed copy: Fullname, Company'
) 
select id, action, type, date, col,
    MAX(case when metatype = 'Metaname' then value end) Name,
    MAX(case when metatype = 'MetaValue' then value end) Value
from data
group by id, action, type, date, col
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7129)

Or you can use a `PIVOT` on the data to get the same result:

```
;with data(id, [action], [type], [date], [col], metatype, value) as
(
    select 41, 'Insert', 'SubscriptionMetaData', '2012-10-19', '53DA4XXX','Metaname', 'Watermark'
    union all
    select 41, 'Insert', 'SubscriptionMetaData', '2012-10-19', '53DA4XXX','MetaValue', 'Licensed copy: Fullname, Company'
) 
select *
from
(
    select id, [action], [type], [date], [col], metatype, value
    from data
) src
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for metatype in (Metaname, MetaValue)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7130)

Both produce the same result:

```
| ID | ACTION |                 TYPE |       DATE |      COL |      NAME |                            VALUE |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 41 | Insert | SubscriptionMetaData | 2012-10-19 | 53DA4XXX | Watermark | Licensed copy: Fullname, Company |
```

Comment: @lontivero Happy to help, just as an FYI if you ever have more that one value for each of the FieldName and FieldValue columns, then this will still work you will have to alter the answer slightly get all of the results to display.

Comment: just one more thing. This is great but i am loosing info. Please, look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7140

Comment: @lontivero can you edit the fiddle and create your full table and some sample data?  It looks like this needs to be adjusted, if you have different values for the `fieldname`, etc. then I will have to change this.

Comment: @lontivero if you have multiple field names that you want to return, then you will want to add more `case` statements similar to this -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f969/9.  If you are going to have a lot of field names, then you might want to consider using a dynamic sql version of the `pivot` query

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a stored procedure or scalar-valued function using the coalesce function as follows:

```
DECLARE @Results NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Token NVARCHAR(5) = '-'; -- separator token
SELECT @Results = coalesce(@Results + @Token,'') + t.MetaValue from (select * from TableName where MetaName = 'SubscriptionMetadata') t;
RETURN @Results; -- variable containing the concatenated values
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a working example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9327/9) Please replace column names as required. `Col3 = your string concatenating column`.

```
SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,
       NameValue =REPLACE( (SELECT col3 AS [data()]
           FROM mytable t2
           WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1
           ORDER BY t2.col1
           FOR XML PATH('')
           ), ' ', ' : ')
FROM mytable t1
GROUP BY col1,col2 ;

--DATA
1 |  X |  Name
1 |  X |  Value

--RESULTS
1 |  X |  Name:Value --Name Value pair here
```

**EDIT: If you don't need concatenation** *(as per your comment)*

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3 NameColumn, t2.col3 ValueColumn
FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col3 = 'Watermark') t1 JOIN 
     (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE NOT (col3 = 'Watermark')) t2 
     ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
```